# Как добавить к динамическим элементам счетчик?

Tags: javascript, jquery, события

Есть формы которые подгружаются динамически (ajax) и у каждой формы есть свой счетчик символов

Как можно заставить его работать правильно? По ссылке есть наброски, но они не работают так, как надо. Функция `Counter()` должна быть универсальна, считается, что поле ввода текста и счетчик всегда находятся в одном div (на данный момент это `.form`), возможно, это можно как-то использовать

```js
function Counter(input, display) {
  $('.main').on('keyup', input, function() {
    var rem = 100 - $(this).val().length;
    $(display).html(rem > 0 ? rem : 'Лимит символов превышен');
  });
};

Counter('.textarea', '.len');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div class="form">
    <textarea class="textarea" name="text"></textarea>
    <div class="len">100</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form">
    <textarea class="textarea" name="text"></textarea>
    <div class="len">100</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form">
    <textarea class="textarea" name="text"></textarea>
    <div class="len">100</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form">
    <textarea class="textarea" name="text"></textarea>
    <div class="len">100</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form">
    <textarea class="textarea" name="text"></textarea>
    <div class="len">100</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bL78yLg3/

Comment: А если .len запрятан куда по дальше + вложен в друге блоки? И, возможно, сам .textarea? http://jsfiddle.net/oaaLwzym/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для произвольного кода

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="form">
        <textarea class="textarea" name="text"></textarea>
        <div>
            <span>
                <div class="len">100</div>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form">
        <div>
            <textarea class="textarea" name="text"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>
                <div class="len">100</div>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form">
        <div class="len">100</div>
        <textarea class="textarea" name="text"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Можно использовать такой js

```
function Counter(input, display) {
    $('.main').on('keyup', input, function() {
        var rem = 100 - $(this).val().length;
        $(this).parents(".form").find(display).html(rem > 0 ? rem  : 'Лимит символов превышен');
    });
};

Counter('.textarea', '.len');
```

Пример http://jsfiddle.net/pgd3b8gf/

Comment: Да, это оно, что-то я позабыл про существование функции parents, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

```js
function Counter(input, display) {
  $('.main').on('keyup', input, function() {
    var rem = 100 - $(this).val().length;
    $(this).parents(".form").find(display).html(rem > 0 ? rem : 'Лимит символов превышен');
  });
};

Counter('.textarea', '.len');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div class="form">
    <textarea class="textarea" name="text"></textarea>
    <div class="len">100</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form">
    <textarea class="textarea" name="text"></textarea>
    <div class="len">100</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form">
    <textarea class="textarea" name="text"></textarea>
    <div class="len">100</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form">
    <textarea class="textarea" name="text"></textarea>
    <div class="len">100</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form">
    <textarea class="textarea" name="text"></textarea>
    <div class="len">100</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я ответил в комментарии

Comment: @Fangog подправил

Comment: @PashaPash, `find(".len")` мухлеж :Р

Comment: @Visman зря что ли класс стоит. надо с пользой его применять!

Comment: @PashaPash, класс стоит во втором параметре, его и надо использовать.

Comment: @Visman подправил. теперь все по честному, без обмана

Comment: @PashaPash, примените ваш js к html из моего сообщения. Во второй textarea у вас работать счетчик не будет.

Comment: @Visman а вы отвечайте сразу ответом, а не ссылкой в фиддл в комментах - и не придется потом мой ленивый копипаст проверять. и, кстати, зачем внешний fiddle в ответе - есть же встроенный в сайт

Comment: @PashaPash, если взялись отвечать, отвечайте не лениво.

Comment: @Visman я взялся вынести ответ-ссылку из комента от участника, который придерживается древней хешкодовской традиции постить ответы в комментариях. наверное, до сих пор путает кнопки после смены интерфейса ;) ну или он еще ленивее меня.